# Show specific data in a index view that belongs to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Creating a simple todolist. Trying to show the description for a **task** that belongs to a list in the **list index view**. With the current code all data fields shows up from all tasks that belongs to the list when i use **list.tasks**, but i only want the **task.desc.** How do i specifically tell rails that i only want the task.desc to show up?

*lists/index.html.erb*

```
<h1>My Lists</h1>

        <%= link_to 'New List', new_list_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

        <h3>Name | Time Ago</h3>

    <% @lists.each do |list| %>

        <h4><%= link_to list.name, list %></td></h4>

        <% if list.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
        <%="#{time_ago_in_words(list.created_at)} ago"%>
        <% else %>
        <h6><%= list.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></h6>

        <%= list.tasks %><br />
            <% end %>


        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(list) %> | 
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', list, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        <br />
    <% end %>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly your problem, you can use .each, which you have used for list iteration:

```
<% list.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= task.desc %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of each description

list.tasks.collect(&:desc)

The & is a Rails shortcut that got into Ruby 1.9 - it says, apply the method after the & to each member of the collection.

I think you **might** want

list.tasks.collect(&:desc).join("<br />").html_safe

:)

(you might not need html_safe, it's used to show you're deliberately putting markup in a string and you don't want it to be escaped)

If this works for you I would take it out of the view and put it in the list class. As in

```
def current_tasks
  tasks.collect(&:desc)
end
```

This means you can test this and reuse it later.